# Citation inside Glossary

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, glossaries

On the "We put \cite{} everywhere" topic, I've source citations in definitions some of my glossary entries.

I use the `unsrt` style. As the Glossary is in the `frontmatter`, one can easily guess that my citation (within the glossary définition) will thus appears first in the bibliography.

Is there a workaround to make the citation order like it appears when the `\gls` command was called ?

I especially think of the workaround with the citations appearing in the toc...

Is there like a `\phantomcite{}` where you can set where the `[XX]` is displayed, and where the `XX` is taken into account for the sorting ?

Here is a MWEB, for completeness'sake :

```
\documentclass{book}    

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage{hyperref} 


%\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key1,
author = {Author, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Title1},
publisher = {Publisher1},
}
@book{key2,
author = {Author, B.},
year = {2001},
title = {Title2},
publisher = {Publisher2},
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[toc,acronym,section=section]{glossaries} 
\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\makeglossaries        %

\glsenableentrycount

\newglossaryentry{glscard}{
    name=cardinality,
    description={The number of elements in the specified set \cite{key1}}}

\newacronym{pc}{PC}{Personal Computer}   
\newacronym{mesh}{MSH}{Mesh Secant Header}   




\setglossarystyle{list}    

\begin{document} 
\printglossary[toctitle=Lexique,type=main]
\printglossary[toctitle=Acronyms,type=acronym]
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{ab}
\cite{key2}
\gls{pc}; \gls{pc};
\gls{glscard} % <--- I want the number of the citation to be [2] as it is quoted here 
\newpage 
\gls{mesh}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib} 


\end{document}
```

And its output. You can clearly see that the citation is the first in the bibliography (`[1]`), even if the second citation (in order of appearance) is after.

[image: Output of the MWE]

Comment: From what I understand `\bibliography{}` adds the bib extension on it's own, try `\bibliography{\jobname}`.  If your bib files are highly controlled you can use `\nocite{*}` before the `\bibliography{}` command, or while very inconvenient - if you urgently need a solution in the interim waiting for a better alternative `\nocite{key1}` can be used within the document (not the preamble) to specifically add that command.

Comment: `\nocite{key1}` will make `key1` appear in the bibliography. But is there a possibility to use its digit `[XX]` and to print it besides the definition in the glossary ?

Comment: The only package I am aware of that will let you print a full citation in a given location (preamble problem not withstanding) is `bibentry` I haven't ever gotten it to work myself, but see if that helps.  If your fine with a bibliography for your glossaries as a whole, consider the `bibunits` package.

Comment: It seems obvious that one whats to use citations in the glossary to give references where the definitions can be found. Is there no convenient way to do this?